# EC2: "Launch Failed Your requested instance type (t2.micro) is not supported in your requested Availability Zone (ap-south-1c)"

Tags: subnet

[image]

I created above architecture  with Mumbai region (I did not select, default value).

When I'm going to lunch the EC2 instance with below VPC, Sub-net and security group attached Im getting below message,

> Launch Failed Your requested instance type (t2.micro) is not supported
> in your requested Availability Zone (ap-south-1c). Please retry your
> request by not specifying an Availability Zone or choosing
> ap-south-1a, ap-south-1b.

But when I launch an EC2 instance without attaching VPC, Subnet,s (With default created vpc and security groups) Its launch successfully.

What is the problem? how can I launh EC2 instance with manually created VPC and Subnets.

Comment: Which AZs are you subnets in?

Comment: Availability Zone - ap-south-1c (aps1-az2)   (I did not select)

Comment: Try creating vpc or new subnet in different AZ, like the answers suggest.

Comment: yes. now working

Comment: Good news: If you take a peek at this the ec2 pricing page you might be surprised to find that your region qualifies for a t3.micro for free: "( t3.micro for the regions in which t2.micro is unavailable)" https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like t2.micro instances are not available in the particular availability zone. As the message says, You can create instances in the other two AZs.

When you launch the EC2 outside of VPC, it is launching the instances from an availability zone that has the capacity to launch the instance class  automatically.

So it does not matter whether you are launching the instance inside the vpc or outside, If you do not specify an availability zone, it will choose a subnet from the availability zone that has the capacity to launch the particular instance class.

Comment: Even within one region, not all availability zones are the same! I tried to launch an m5.large EC2 instance in us-east-1, and it worked in every availability zone _except_ "e".

Answer (score 0):

Some Availability Zones don't support particular instance types.

> Some Availability Zones don't support particular instance types. If you receive the error "Your requested instance type is not supported in your requested Availability Zone," do the following: Determine which Availability Zones support your instance type. Retry the request and specify an Availability Zone that supports your chosen instance type. Or, submit the request without specifying an Availability Zone.

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-instance-type-not-supported-az-error/